# Azure functions runtime binding failing for System.IO.Packaging using OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I have a project which ran fine as an Azure Function in v1 of the Functions runtime, but I'm busy rewriting it for v2 and I'm stuck.

My Azure Function relies on a library of mine, which in turn depends on another library. Both libraries depend on the Open XML SDK, which I've installed in those projects via NuGet. They both also have System.IO.Packaging installed via NuGet.

If I run my code through a console app, it runs fine. When I try to run it as an Azure Function, it gets partway through my library code but then the functions runtime falls over with the error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: getWorkbook. ExcelGenerator: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.IO.Packaging, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

I've tried adding System.IO.Packaging to the Azure Function project (which I realise I ought not to need to do) but it then falls over with a new error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   getWorkbook. ExcelGenerator: Could not load type
>   'System.IO.Packaging.CompressionOption' from assembly 'WindowsBase,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I'm suspicious about the 0.0.0.0 version number in the first error, and I really don't understand the second one (or honestly why adding System.IO.Packaging to the Azure Function makes any difference at all, given that this is just running compiled library code).

One other curious thing is that WindowsBase does not show up in the "Assemblies" dependency list for my Azure Function, but it *does* show up checked in the "add reference" dialog box. If I uncheck it, I get a mysterious error saying "No assembly reference with the name "{0}" could be found in the project".

I'm pretty sure somehow System.IO.Packaging or WindowsBase just isn't making it through to the Azure deployment, but I'm not sure how. I'm rapidly discovering that I don't know very much about how DLL dependencies work at all let alone in Azure - any ideas?

Comment: `If I run my code through a console app, it runs fine.` Is it a .Net Core console app? If so could you share how do you rewrite the function to v2, e.g the `FunctionProjectName.csproj` content?

Comment: It's a .Net Framework 4.6.1 console app. The target for my Azure portion (which is really just a very small .cs that immediately calls my library) is also .Net Framework 4.6.1. Can share anything else from the .csproj if it would help!

Comment: To work with ~2 Function runtime, we need to test code with .net core target framework(`netcoreapp2.1`). And if you meet any assembly problem then, try the code in .net core console app to see whether it's a .net core problem or related to Function runtime.

Comment: I created a new console app targeting .NET Core 2.1. It didn't work initially, but I added NuGet packages for System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager and System.IO.Packaging and it now runs fine. I excitedly added a NuGet package for System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager to my Azure Functions project, but unfortunately it fails (with the second error above, the WindowsBase one). Could it be that the kinda weirdly broken WindowsBase reference in my Azure Function code is the culprit?

Comment: Have you changed TargetFramework of Function project to `netcoreapp2.1`?

Comment: Oh wow. You are a life saver. This works great, and I really was completely out of ideas of what was wrong. If you are willing to write up an answer saying this I'll send through a bounty!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your generosity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite v1 function to v2, right click on Function project, and `Edit FunctionProjectName.csproj`, change `TargetFramework` of Function project to `netcoreapp2.1`, `AzureFunctionsVersion` to `v2`.

And we may have to install [packages for v2 function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions#what-nuget-packages-do-i-need) as they are not built-in any more as in v1.

Code refactoring is necessary, if we meet any assembly problem then, try the code in .Net Core console app to see whether it's a .net core problem or related to Function runtime.

If there're some configurations in [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json), need pay attention as some of their format has been changed.

Usually, creating a template v2 function and compare old content with new v2 template is recommended.